# Liferay 6.2 theme integration

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme

I get a theme source code developed on Liferay.
I imported it as Liferay project from existing source.
I deployed it.
But no changes occurs on my website theme.
Can anyone help with a solution or some hints please.

Comment: Did you applied theme from site pages? Did you imported theme as plugin sdk or maven project.

Comment: Yes, I imported it from plugin sdk, then deployed it. when i go to site pages, I can't see it on available themes!! Only default liferay theme appears. Any idea about what the problem may be?

Comment: can you paste log from tomcat while you deploy theme. also log from you plugin sdk when you ran ant deploy

Comment: It may be because of the cache ... find the hidden .docroot/css/.sass-cache
 files and remove them .